# What does it mean to localise a ring, at a prime, in this context?

Tags: ring-theory

Given a chain of prime ideals of a commutative ring $R$, $P_1 \subseteq P_2 \subseteq Q$. Then what does it mean to localise the chain at $Q$?

I know what the localisation of a ring is. But I don't know what is meant by localising the chain at $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should just mean applying the localization functor to the chain.

After localizing $R$ at $Q$ (using the complement of $Q$ as a multiplicatively closed set), you have the local ring $R_Q$ with unique maximal ideal $Q_Q$, and there will be localized ideals $(P_{1})_{Q}\subseteq (P_{2})_{Q}\subseteq Q_Q $ corresponding to the original chain.